# How can I batch rename a set of filenames in Linux?

Tags: bash, rename

I have a folder with images named:

```
pic001-2.png
pic002-2.png
pic003-2.png
```

How do I rename them to the following?

```
pic001.png
pic002.png
pic003.png
```

I have tried `mv "pic*-2.png" "pic*.png"` but keep getting errors.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This will delete the first `-2` found in each filename:

```
for f in pic*-2.png; do
  mv "$f" "${f/-2/}"
done
```

To test it, just prepend `echo` to the `mv` line.

Answer (score 9):

You need the appropriately named 'rename' command!

Try something like this:

```
rename 's/(pic\d+)-\d\.jpg/$1.jpg/' pic*.jpg
```

It takes a perl regular expression as the first argument, so your pattern-matching and manipulation options are pretty extensive.  See the rename(1) man page for full details.